# what is the difference between brewed python and system python on OS X

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

what is the difference between brewed python and system python? Which one of them is recommended in which case? I use often brew package manager.

Comment: Recommended in which case? Usually you use system one (P2), unless you need upgraded version, such as Python 3 or extra libraries, then you use brewed one.

Answer (score 2):

System python is only as up-to-date as the OS itself, so there is no guarantee that you have the most recent version of Python. Additionally, system python is only Python 2.

Brewed python has two advantages:

1. More up to date
2. Python 3 instead of 2